# Why does this Laravel eloquent query give back more objects?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get back a model that has relationships with other models in Laravel with eloquent but my query does not work. What i am trying to do is only
show the dataLog with the related groups, units and the related component and give that back as a object. The parameter $componentId is the only component that should be given back but it gives back other
component ids, groups and units aswell. Is there a way to only show the component with the given parameter componentId and skip the rest that is not relevant?

```
<?   

   public function getLogData( $componentId, $limit ) {

        $dataLogs = Log::whereHas( 'groups', function( $group ) use (&$componentId) {
            $group->whereHas( "units", function( $unit ) use (&$componentId) {
                $unit->whereHas( "components", function( $component ) use (&$componentId) {
                    $component->where( "Component", $componentId );
                } );
            } );
        } )->take( $limit )->get();


        return response( )->json( $dataLogs );


    }
    
?>
```

The response is

```
[
{
    "Oid": 10409376,
    "Active": false,
    "Speed": "0",
    "Weight": "0",
    "Amount": "0",
    "Code": "",
    "Control": false,
    "Type": 1,
    "Event": 1,
    "Name": "TestName",
    "Number": "",
    "Mode": 0,
    "Recipe": "",
    "DateTime": "2020-03-02 11:09:37.177",
    "Check": 288,
    "groups": [
    {
        "Oid": 11162074,
        "Amount": "3.387",
        "Cap": "0",
        "Speed": "0",
        "ActTachoVoltage": "0",
        "Act": "0",
        "Weight": "497717",
        "Codes": "",
        "Type": 1,
        "Name": "Group1",
        "units": [
            {
            "Oid": 15934577,
            "Speed": "0",
            "Counter": 0,
            "Weight": "0",
            "components": [
                    {
                    "oId": 18168546,
                    "Type": 1,
                    "component": 1102,
                    "Entry": 15934577
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
            "Oid": 15934578,
            "Speed": "0",
            "Counter": 0,
            "Weight": "0",
            "components": [
                    {
                    "oId": 18168546,
                    "Type": 1,
                    "component": 1101,
                    "Entry": 15934577
                    }
                ]
            },
}
]
```

The response that is needed with the given query

```
[
{
    "Oid": 10409376,
    "Active": false,
    "Speed": "0",
    "Weight": "0",
    "Amount": "0",
    "Code": "",
    "Control": false,
    "Type": 1,
    "Event": 1,
    "Name": "TestName",
    "Number": "",
    "Mode": 0,
    "Recipe": "",
    "DateTime": "2020-03-02 11:09:37.177",
    "Check": 288,
    "groups": [
    {
        "Oid": 11162074,
        "Amount": "3.387",
        "Cap": "0",
        "Speed": "0",
        "ActTachoVoltage": "0",
        "Act": "0",
        "Weight": "497717",
        "Codes": "",
        "Type": 1,
        "Name": "Group1",
        "units": [
            {
            "Oid": 15934577,
            "Speed": "0",
            "Counter": 0,
            "Weight": "0",
            "components": [
            {
            "Oid": 15934578,
            "Speed": "0",
            "Counter": 0,
            "Weight": "0",
            "components": [
                    {
                    "oId": 18168546,
                    "Type": 1,
                    "component": 1101,
                    "Entry": 15934577
                    }
                ]
            },
}
]
```

If the parameter id given is 1101. Does any one know what i am doing wrong?

The models and the relation ships

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class log extends Model
{

    // Define variables
    protected $primaryKey = 'Oid';
    protected $table = 'log';
    protected $connection = 'testdb';
    protected $appends = [ 'groups' ];

    // Functions
    public function getGroupsAttribute( )
    {
        if( $this->groups() )
            return $this->groups()->get();

        return [];
    }

    // Define model relationship logEntry = FK from log to group model 
    public function groups(){
        return $this->hasMany(groupLog::class, 'logEntry');
    }

}


?>


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class groupLog extends Model
{

    // Define variables
    protected $primaryKey = 'Oid';
    protected $table = 'groupLog';
    protected $connection = 'testdb';

    // Functions
    public function getUnitsAttribute( )
    {
        if( $this->units() )
            return $this->units()->get();

        return [];
    }

    // Define database relationships
    public function log(){
        return $this->belongsTo(log::class);
    }

    // Define model relationship groupEntry = FK from log to group model 
    public function units(){
        return $this->hasMany(unitLog::class, 'groupEntry');
    }


}

?>


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class unitLog extends Model
{

    // Define variables
    protected $primaryKey = 'Oid';
    protected $table = 'unitLog';
    protected $connection = 'testdb';
    protected $appends = [ 'components' ];

    // Functions
    public function getComponentsAttribute( )
    {
        if( $this->components() )
            return $this->components()->get();

        return [];
    }

    // Database relationships with models
    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo(groupLog::class);
    }

    public function components(){
        return $this->hasMany(componentLog::class, 'unitEntry');
    }

}

?>


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class componentLog extends Model
{
    // Define variables
    protected $primaryKey = 'Oid';
    protected $table = 'componentLog';
    protected $connection = 'testdb';

    // Define model database relationships
    public function units(){
        return $this->belongsTo(unitLog::class);
    }

}

?>
```

Tried the solution with the answer like so

```
        $machineLogs = MachineLog::whereHas( 'groups', function($group) use ($componentId) {
            $group->whereHas( "units", function( $unit ) use ($componentId) {
                $unit->whereHas( "components", function( $component ) use ($componentId) {
                    $component->where("component", $componentId);
                } );
            } );
        } );

        $filterComponents = $machineLogs->with(['groups.units.components' => function ($query) use ($componentId) {
            $query->where('component', $componentId);
        }])->take($limit)->get();

        return response( )->json( $filterComponents );
```

Comment: please share the code where you load those relations

Comment: Why don't you do it the other way around?
Getting component with componentId  = $componentId with the parent Unit with the parent Group with the parent Log if these were all 1-to-many relations

Comment: Can you post your database table structure?

Comment: Please learn syntax standards, database naming etc. Use PSR-2 for syntax and see how Laravels naming conventions is, tbh your code is horrific to look at :) all those weird spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying Log that has the given units and it will always return all the units, no matter what ids they have. What you are looking for is to filter the relationship using `with()`. I would still use your full query, for getting the correct logs out.

```
Log::yourQueries() // insert your existing queries here.
    ->with('groups.units.components' => function ($query) use ($componentId) {
        $query->where('component', $componentId);
    });
```

This will preload components and filter them by the giving query, this should return your expected result.

Comment: Hello mrhn thank you for your answer. I am still getting the same exact result trying to implement the ->with filter. Il add the code how i implemented the ->with filter above.